# How to answer to ajax request while receiving MQTT messages

Tags: php, ajax, mqtt, phpmqtt

I'm fairly new to PHP and MQTT and I'm trying to figure out how to answer to an Ajax request (from the JavaScript front-end) while receiving MQTT messages. The goal is to update the web page with the new data received. I'm aware I can use WebSockets and send the incoming messages directly from the PHP page, but for several reasons I don't want to use WebSockets here.

So far, here the code I use to answer to Ajax requests:

```
<?php
$result = [];
$result['success'] = false;
$result['message'] = "unknown";

if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'quit':
            $msg = shell_exec('sudo systemctl stop startup.service');
            $result['success'] = true;
            $result['message'] = $msg;
            break;

        case 'restart':
            $msg = shell_exec('sudo systemctl restart startup.service');
            $result['success'] = true;
            $result['message'] = $msg;
            break;

        case "do-something":
            // do something!
            $result['success'] = "true|false";
            $result['message'] = "blabla";
            break;    
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

and here the code I use to receive MQTT messages:

```
<?php 
require('vendor/autoload.php');
use PhpMqtt\Client\MqttClient;
use PhpMqtt\Client\ConnectionSettings;

$server   = '<address>';
$port     = 1883;
$clientId = 'id';
$username = '<user>';
$password = '<password>';

$mqtt = new MqttClient($server, $port, $clientId);

$connectionSettings = (new ConnectionSettings)
  ->setUsername($username)
  ->setPassword($password)
  ->setKeepAliveInterval(60)
  ->setLastWillQualityOfService(1);

$mqtt->connect($connectionSettings, true);
$mqtt->subscribe('wsc/power', function ($topic, $message) {
    printf("Received message on topic [%s]: %s\n", $topic, $message);
}, 0);
$mqtt->loop(true);
```

What I don't understand is how to join the two snippets.
The MQTT one enables its own loop so any instruction placed after `$mqtt->loop(true);` is not executed.

How to handle async requests while the loop is active?

Comment: The best answer here is to not do this in PHP, but to run a JavaScript MQTT client in the browser and MQTT over WebSockets.

Comment: @hardillb I came from that approach but I don't like it because I have to put the MQTT credentials in the JavaScript file

Comment: asynchronous tasks like receiving MQTT messages while responding to AJAX requests in a PHP can be difficult due to PHP's synchronous, single-threaded nature.
If you dont want to use Websockets you can use a Database or File to Store MQTT Messages.

Comment: @Mark use ephemeral credentials that can only be used once and issue new ones each time the page is loaded. They are only needed at the point of connection.

Comment: You can run a PHP worker that subscribes to MQTT topics and persists that messages somewhere (d.h. in a database or Redis). You can then have the frontend poll new messages from the backend which accesses the same data store. Joining both things together is rather complicated as your frontend never knows when the backend receives new MQTT messages and you don't want to let requests wait for too long since they block your PHP workers and therefore resources.